# BusyBox Date Command Set Time with UNIX Timestamp

Tags: linux, date, busybox

In bash, the following works for setting the date from a UNIX timestamp ( seconds from the epoch ):

```
date +%s -s @`date +%s`
```

In Busybox, this does not work. How can I do the same for the date command with Busybox? Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try

```
date @`date +%s`
```

I don't think it's got anything to do with bash.

[Busybox's `date` command](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html#date) is a lightweight version of the more classic [GNU/FSF `date`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/date.1.html)

Comment: FWIW, this should now read:  `date -su \`date ++%s\`` to properly set the clock with the resultant UTC string.