# How can I convert a date with a named month to a unix timestamp with only Busybox tools?

Tags: linux, date, busybox

I'm working in an environment where I pretty much only have access to busybox tools, and trying to convert a date in the format `Mon Jan 1 23:59:59 2018 GMT` to a unix timestamp, in a shell script. I can't change the format of the input time I am parsing. It seems that `busybox date` can not understand this date format, or any other format with a named month. I have a really ugly script that can do it, but does anyone know of anything nicer?

Edit: the `date -D` option doesn't work for me, I get

```
date: invalid option -- 'D'     
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2018-01-11 16:07:45 PST) multi-call binary.     

Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]`
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [BusyBox Date Command Set Time with UNIX Timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339938/busybox-date-command-set-time-with-unix-timestamp)

Comment: See also: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/296073/117549

Comment: @JeffSchaller No, the [BusyBox Date Command Set Time with UNIX Timestamp](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/339938/busybox-date-command-set-time-with-unix-timestamp) is about setting the computer time, it does not use the `-d` option for a date string.

Comment: Thanks, @isaac; I'll retract my vote to avoid misleading others.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The busybox `date`<sup>2</sup> is fully capable of parsing the date in the given string with some help<sup>1</sup> (except for the GMT time zone).

```
$ gdate='Mon Jan 1 23:59:59 2018 GMT'
$ TZ=GMT0 busybox date -d "$gdate" -D '%a %b %d %T %Y %Z'
Mon Jan  1 23:59:59 GMT 2018
```

The help is given with the `-D` option: a description of the source format.

To get a UNIX timestamp, just add the output format expected `+'%s'`:

```
$  TZ=GMT0 busybox date -d "$gdate" -D '%a %b %d %T %Y %Z' +'%s'
1514851199
```

---

<sup>1</sup>
The busybox `date` has most of the GNU `date` command's capabilities and one that the GNU `date` command doesn't: the `-D` option. Get the busybox help as follows:

```
$ busybox date --help
```

> BusyBox v1.27.2 (Debian 1:1.27.2-2) multi-call binary.
>
> Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]
>
> Display time (using +FMT), or set time
>
> ```
>     [-s,--set] TIME Set time to TIME
>     -u,--utc        Work in UTC (don't convert to local time)
>     -R,--rfc-2822   Output RFC-2822 compliant date string
>     -I[SPEC]        Output ISO-8601 compliant date string
>                     SPEC='date' (default) for date only,
>                     'hours', 'minutes', or 'seconds' for date and
>                     time to the indicated precision
>     -r,--reference FILE     Display last modification time of FILE
>     -d,--date TIME  Display TIME, not 'now'
>     -D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion
> ```

Note the `-D FMT` option.

---

<sup>2</sup>
Note that you may be able to call busybox `date` in two ways:

```
$ busybox date
```

Or, if a link to `busybox` with the name `date` has been installed in the correct `PATH` directory:

```
$ date
```

To verify, just ask for `--version` or `--help` to find out which date you have installed.

With GNU `date`:

```
$ date --version
date (GNU coreutils) 8.28
```

Or (busybox `date`):

```
$ date --help
BusyBox v1.27.2 (Debian 1:1.27.2-2) multi-call binary.
…
…
```

Comment: I guess I must have a different busybox version than you're using here, all I get with your example is 
`date: invalid option -- 'D'
BusyBox v1.24.1 (2018-01-11 16:07:45 PST) multi-call binary.

Usage: date [OPTIONS] [+FMT] [TIME]`.
It's a good answer though, I'll probably accept it if I don't get anything that will work for me here.

Comment: Actually I'm not sure how that works at all... from the documentation here https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html there is a set of recognized TIME formats, none of which include a named month

Comment: @Nic The [version 1.24.0 is from January-2017](https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/). Strange: I downloaded that version (busybox-i686) from that link and it has the `-D FMT` option. Also (at the same link) you can download [busybox 1.27](https://busybox.net/downloads/binaries/1.27.1-i686/busybox), it is just of size 900k Byte.

Comment: @Nic On re-reading the documentation on [the page you link to](https://busybox.net/downloads/BusyBox.html) it is clear that the last option is `-D FMT          Use FMT for -d TIME conversion`. You should be able to see it.

Comment: I see it there, and it works on my host machine, but unfortunately just doesn't work on the yocto image I'm working with